# Proper use of "delineate"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Is this the proper use of delineate in this sentence?

"In order to properly discuss the differences between amateur and professional critics it is necessary to delineate between the two."

Or should it be "...delineate the two."?

Comment: [This NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=delineate+between+them%2Cdelineate+them&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdelineate%20between%20them%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdelineate%20them%3B%2Cc0) should convince you that ***between*** isn't normally used in this construction.

Comment: So the best thing would be to say "...delineate them"? @FumbleFingers

Comment: Well, I only really changed your ***the two*** to ***them*** because I figured it would be more common. With [your exact version](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=delineate+between+the+two%2Cdelineate+the+two&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdelineate%20between%20the%20two%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdelineate%20the%20two%3B%2Cc0) there are in fact relatively more instances using ***between***, but since I think ***the two*** is less "natural" in the first place, I think this just reflects the fact that they're from "less than competent" writers

Comment: (i.e. - they're probably mostly from people who don't know the difference between ***delineate*** and ***distinguish***)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I wouldn't use delineate here because it doesn't add anything to the sentence at all -- and worse, it's essentially redundant.

*Delineate* means *to describe precisely*; right now, what's been written is effectively the following:

> In order to properly discuss the differences between [A] and [B], it is necessary to [discuss the differences between A and B]."

Instead, I would just state the differences:

> The principal differences between amateur and professional critics are [X], [Y], and [Z].

Comment: I see the reciprocity, I thought the same.

Comment: I can't find a definition for "delineate" that includes "to draw a distinction between".

Comment: I couldn't find a (authoritative) source either. Edited, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to say "we must first describe each", then you could say "*it is necessary to delineate the two*".

If you intend to say "we must first describe the line that distinguishes the two", then you could say "*it is necessary to delineate the boundary between the two*".